# Win7 R 3.2.2 RStudio 0.99.473. Errors installing package Hmisc

Tags: r, install.packages

I am unable to install the package Hmisc.  The command install.packages(Hmisc) yields: Error in install.packages : object 'Hmisc' not found.

I downloaded the zip file from CRAN, then ran install.packages(pkgs="F:/Temp/Hmisc_3.16-0.zip").  That yields:
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Athena/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘F:/Temp/Hmisc_3.16-0.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

I am running Win7, R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety", and RStudio Version 0.99.473.

Is there a fix I can try?

Answer (score 2):

The package name should be in quotes, so:

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
```

Without quotes, you are passing a variable called `Hmisc` which most likely has not been assigned hence the `object 'Hmisc' not found` error.

To install a package from source you need to set `repos=NULL` and `type="source"`:

```
install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")
```